# Why is multithreading slower?

Tags: c, multithreading, time, multiprocess

A multi-process and multi-threaded implementation of three linked lists with 1000000 nodes using merge sort was implemented.
I compared the real-time of the implemented program, but the multi-thread method is slower.
Why is that?

main method in process.c

```
    /* Insert nodes */
    Node* tmp = NULL;   
    int num;    
    for( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )
    {
        fscanf(fread,"%d",&num);    
        tmp = createNode(num , i ); 
        insertNode( &list1.head, &list1.tail, tmp );
        tmp = createNode(num , i ); 
        insertNode( &list2.head, &list2.tail, tmp );    
        tmp = createNode(num , i );
        insertNode( &list3.head, &list3.tail, tmp );    
        tmp = createNode(num , i ); 
    }
    free( tmp );    
    fclose(fread);  

    if ((t1 = times(&mytms)) == -1) {
        perror("times 1");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid1= fork();   
    if(pid1==0){
        mergeSort( &list1.head );   
        file_output(&list1);    
        freeAll( list1.head );
        exit(1);    
    }
    pid2= fork();   
    if(pid2==0){
        mergeSort( &list2.head );   
        file_output(&list2);    
        freeAll( list2.head );  
        exit(2);    
    }
    pid3 = fork();
    if(pid3==0){
        mergeSort( &list3.head );   
        file_output(&list3);    
        freeAll( list3.head );  
        exit(3);    
    }

    wait(&status);  
    wait(&status);
    wait(&status);

    if ((t2 = times(&mytms)) == -1) {   
        perror("times 2");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Real time : %.5f sec\n", (double)(t2 - t1) / CLK_TCK);
    printf("User time : %.5f sec\n", (double)mytms.tms_utime / CLK_TCK);
    printf("System time : %.5f sec\n", (double)mytms.tms_stime / CLK_TCK);
```

Result
real-time : 1.65

main in thread.c

```
   /* Insert nodes */
   Node* tmp = NULL;   
   int num;           

   for( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )
   {
      fscanf(fread,"%d",&num); 
      tmp = createNode(num , i ); 
      insertNode( &list1.head, &list1.tail, tmp );  
      tmp = createNode(num , i );  
      insertNode( &list2.head, &list2.tail, tmp );  
      tmp = createNode(num , i );  
      insertNode( &list3.head, &list3.tail, tmp );  
   }

   free( tmp );
   fclose(fread);  

   if ((t1 = times(&mytms)) == -1) {
        perror("times 1");
        exit(1);
   }

   pthread_create( &t_id1, NULL, thread_func, &list1 );
   pthread_create( &t_id2, NULL, thread_func, &list2 );
   pthread_create( &t_id3, NULL, thread_func, &list3 );

   pthread_join( t_id1, (void*)&status );
   pthread_join( t_id2, (void*)&status );
   pthread_join( t_id3, (void*)&status );

   if ((t2 = times(&mytms)) == -1) {
        perror("times 2");
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("Real time : %.5f sec\n", (double)(t2 - t1) / CLK_TCK);
   printf("User time : %.5f sec\n", (double)mytms.tms_utime / CLK_TCK);  
   printf("System time : %.5f sec\n", (double)mytms.tms_stime / CLK_TCK);
```

result
real-time 2.27

Comment: It's unclear which parts of this code belong to which functions. Please create a proper [mcve] that others can copy-paste and try out themselves

Comment: Threads and child processes merge sort random 1,000,000 nodes, then fwrite and free them.

Comment: You could probably write a simpler example to prove/demonstrate the point. Something with simple calculations rather than linked lists and sorting.

Comment: I suspect that the processes that you create via `fork` are still running when you output the results from the main process.

Comment: Isn't the parent process blocked because it waits?

Comment: You have 3 consecutive calls to `wait(&status);`. How would the 2nd call differ from the 1st? What is `status`? At best that will wait for the same thing 3 times, resulting in only 1 wait.

Comment: I checked the status value, and it was output differently as 1,2,3. Didn't exit() return? If yes, the three child processes have ended

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, `wait(&status)` waits for _any_ child process to "change state" (usually, to terminate.) The `status` argument effectively is an `OUT` parameter through which the `wait()` call returns the exit status of the child that terminated. If a program forks three times, and then calls `wait()` three times, then it should be safe to assume\* that all three children have terminated after the third `wait()` returns.

Comment: \* It's never _really_ safe to assume... There are other events that could cause `wait()` to return, but probably won't happen in this simple example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ### Why is multithreading slower?

It is processor specific and tied to the number of [cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor), the organization of [CPU caches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache), their [cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence), your [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory). See also tests and benchmarks on https://www.phoronix.com/ ; it won't be the same on Intel Core i7 10700K and on AMD Ryzen 9 3900X (whose price are close).

It is also both [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) and [optimization specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler). Read the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and a good [book on Computer Architecture](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/0128119055?tag=duckduckgo-ffab-fr-21&linkCode=osi&th=1&psc=1).

It also depends upon your particular [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) and your particular [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (e.g. [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) is not the same as [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/)), and `glibc 2.31` could have different performance than `glibc 2.30` on the *same* computer. Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/), [pthreads(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html), [nptl(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/nptl.7.html), [numa(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/numa.7.html), [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), [madvise(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Did you try on a recent Linux with a recent [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) invoked [as](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -O3 -mtune=native` at least?

You could use [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) then [hwinfo](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Hwinfo) on Linux to query your hardware.

You might be interested in [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL), [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), or [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC), and you should read about optimization options of your particular C compiler. For recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC). You could even customize your recent GCC with your [GCC plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to improve optimizations, and you could try a recent [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) or [icc](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/compilers.html) compiler.

See also the [MILEPOST GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC) project and the [CTuning one](https://ctuning.org/). Read also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report. Attend ACM [SIGPLAN](http://www.sigplan.org/) and [SIGOPS](https://www.sigops.org/) conferences. Contact computer science academics near you.

<sup>you probably could get a PhD while understanding the answer to your question.</sup>

Comment: Linux version is ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS .

Comment: I tried compiling with the option you provided, but the process is 1.62second, the thread is 1.8 second.process is still faster.

Comment: Consider subcontracting the optimization of your particular program to experts.

Comment: I sent an email. I'm sorry the comment isn't English